# Why can't I set Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, cultureinfo

I have a WCF Service where I set the CurrentCulture and the CurrentUICulture to ensure my resources are properly localized. Sometimes it seems to work but sometimes setting it seems to be ignored.

[image]

As you can see here, the value "de-DE" is assigned, but the CurrentCulture of the thread seems to ignore it.

Comment: Where do you set the culture? Maybe your thread is already started at the moment if setting the culture. Or you set it from another thread

Comment: It's already started. I am trying to change the culture of the thread I am currently on. The thread gets automatically created by the framework.

Comment: It really depends on where you are setting this, where are you doing this at? If your application is already running and you try and change per say, the UICulture, it wont reflect immediately; you have to do these beforehand.

Comment: Have you seen this behavior with hard coded values (rather than the session ones?)

Comment: The culture of the client is in the session.Context.CurrentCulture property. When the user calls an operation on the server. Inside the server operation this code is executed.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: `culture of the client is in the session.Context.CurrentCulture property` what are you using then, `asp` etc.?

Comment: As an experiment, what happens if you execute the following line of code just before you assign the culture: `AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Globalization.NoAsyncCurrentCulture", false);`

Comment: This is a debugger artifact.  Ideally the debugger evaluates expressions in the context of the currently active thread.  But that isn't always possible, in circumstances that are not documented that I know of.  In which case it uses a dedicated "debug thread".  So Thread.CurrentThread tells you about the state of that debug thread, not your thread.  Keep going, not a real problem.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: No, a self hosted wcf service as windows service.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: 4.8